# C# - How to be sure that app has unzip file correctly?

Tags: c#, .net, zip, unzip

I am using Ionic.Zip library to unzip my .zip file. Sometimes this operation is not finished correctly, I mean sometimes one or two small files are missing.
How can I prevent this?

Comment: Any way you can get a checksum of the files before they're zipped and compare that value to one generated after they've been unzipped? Do all the files appear *in* the zip, but once unzipped they're gone / damaged?

Comment: Yes, i am comparing checksum, but how can i be as secure as possible while unzipping? What possible errors can occurs?